# Download Image stored as Binary File in SQL Server using ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm developing an app which stores various records on people. These records require an Image. I am storing the image as a binary file.

At the moment I can choose the image, store it and view it but my application requires to be able to download the image from SQL Server to be able to print.

Here is what I have so far for a method to download an image:

```
 public FileContentResult ViewRecord(int? id)
    {
        if (id == 0) { return null; }
        Record record = new Record();
        ChurchDBContext db = new ChurchDBContext();
        record = db.Records.Where(a => a.RecordId == id).SingleOrDefault();
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=file.pdf"); //this will open in a new tab.. remove if you want to open in the same tab.
        return File(record.Document, "application/pdf");
    }
```

The expected result of this should be a new tab with the image as the pdf but when I click the ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download Record", "ViewRecord", "RecordsContoller", new { id = Model.RecordId }, new { @target = "_blank" })
```

It gives me "Resource not found".

I've tried tinkering with it and looking for more information but I can't find anything useful.

Comment: Did you debug whether you are getting proper bytes in `record` object?

Comment: Or more generally: what diagnostic steps have you taken so far? Assuming you're able to do all of this in the debugger, did you get the rid ID in the `ViewRecord` call? Did you then step through? What happened on each line? Note that creating a new `Record()` object is almost certainly pointless, and if `SingleOrDefault()` returns `null`, you'll then throw a `NullReferenceException` in the last line - you should think about what you want to happen in the case where the given ID doesn't exist.

Comment: Your controller name seems to have typo mistake, i.e. `RecordsContoller`. I believe, it should be `RecordsController`

Comment: @AkashKC my problem was calling it RecordsController instead of just Records!

Comment: @ChloeFinn : You can call it with full controller name as well. You've typ mistake in the controller name when using in `ActionLink`